# Showing both "adb status-window" and "adb logcat" on the same terminal

Tags: wi-fi, adb

I am attempting to get the `adb status-window` command to display anything useful, however it appears to be just showing the following:

> Android Debug Bridge
>   State: device

At first, I figured it was because the resource was busy with an existing operation `adb logcat`, but stopping this failed to fix the issue.

This is for a device that is outside of my local machine and is being used under adb over WiFi.

Is it possible to have these two commands at once? Does the `status-window` work remotely? Why would this not display?

Thanks for looking into this as no real reference was available after some considerable searching.

Comment: What else are you expecting as an output? If the device is not connected, via USB or Wi-Fi, the state would be 'unknown'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my testing, `adb status-window` will *continuously* monitor the status of the ADB (whether it's connected to a device or not). While it's active, connecting a device will show

> Android Debug Bridge
>   State: device

and disconnecting it will show

> Android Debug Bridge
>   State: unknown

On the other hand, `adb logcat` also *continuously* monitors the log from the device. As far as I know, you can't run both of them on the same terminal (tested on Windows' command prompt, though I don't have any idea on other OS). The only workaround is to use multiple terminals to run each command.

---

So, to answer your questions directly,

> Is it possible to have these two commands at once?

AFAIK, no, on Windows' command prompt, but maybe possible with some tricks on others.

> Does the `status-window` work remotely?

Yes.

> Why would this not display?

Because it continuously monitor the status of the ADB.